# Put all dates from HTML tag <span> into a list using BeatifulSoup

Tags: python

There is my HTML file:

```
[<small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
<span><i data-icon="clock"></i>Today 10:52</span>
</small>]
[<small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
<span><i data-icon="clock"></i>April 11</span>
</small>]
[<small class="breadcrumb x-normal">
<span><i data-icon="clock"></i>April 5</span>
</small>]
<span><i data-icon="clock"></i>February 29</span>
</small>]
```

How do I put all these dates into a list.

Here it is my code:

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import lxml

    def get_dates(html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            dates = soup.pass
            print (date)

  get_dates(html.text)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Looks like you forgot to ask a question? See [ask].

Comment: _It doesn't works like this._ That is nowhere near enough, please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. _There is my HTML file:_ That's doesn't look like valid HTML to me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<small class="breadcrumb x-normal"><span><i data-icon="clock"></i>Today 10:52</span></small>' \
       '<small class="breadcrumb x-normal"><span><i data-icon="clock"></i>April 11</span></small>' \
       '<small class="breadcrumb x-normal"><span><i data-icon="clock"></i>April 5</span></small>' \
       '<small class="breadcrumb x-normal"><span><i data-icon="clock"></i>February 29</span></small>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
date_list = []
dates = soup.find_all('small', {'class':'breadcrumb x-normal'})

for date in dates:
    print(date.text)
    date_list.append(date.text)


print(date_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<small class="breadcrumb x-normal"><span><i data-icon="clock"></i>Today 10:52</span></small>' \
       '<small class="breadcrumb x-normal"><span><i data-icon="clock"></i>April 11</span></small>' \
       '<small class="breadcrumb x-normal"><span><i data-icon="clock"></i>April 5</span></small>' \
       '<small class="breadcrumb x-normal"><span><i data-icon="clock"></i>February 29</span></small>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

data = [item.next_element for item in soup.findAll(
    "i", {'data-icon': 'clock'})]

print(data)
```

Output:

```
['Today 10:52', 'April 11', 'April 5', 'February 29']
```